# Resizing D3 Area Chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 area chart which is being drawn just as I want it. I have tried to make it resize with the window. It resizes correctly horizontally, but vertically it seems to be set based on its original height. This is using Safari 9.0.2.  It's difficult to describe what its doing so here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

#graph 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>

<body>
<svg id="graph"></svg>

<script>

var width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width"));
var height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height"));

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var actual = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.actual); });

var svg = d3.select("#graph")

function resize() 
{
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width"))
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height"));

    xScale.range([0, width]);
    yScale.range([height, 0]);

    svg.selectAll("#actual")
       .attr("d", actual);
}

d3.select(window).on('resize', resize); 

d3.csv("areachart.csv", function(error, data) 
{
    data.forEach(function(d, i) 
    {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.actual = +d.actual;
    });

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.actual; })]);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "actual")
        .datum(data)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr("d", actual);

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the areachart.csv:

```
date,actual
1-Jan-16,400
1-Feb-16,500
1-Mar-16,634
1-Apr-16,408
1-May-16,185
1-Jun-16,500
1-Jul-16,467
1-Aug-16,456
1-Sep-16,900
1-Oct-16,108
1-Nov-16,200
1-Dec-16,466
```

Does anyone know how to fix this please? Thanks. Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you fengshui for your help. I finally got it working. Here is my full answer:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #graph 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<body>
<svg id="graph"></svg>

<script>

var width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width"));
var height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height"));

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

function actualArea()
{
    var actual = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.actual); });
    return actual
}

var svg = d3.select("#graph")

function resize() 
{
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width"))
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height"));

    xScale.range([0, width]);
    yScale.range([height, 0]);

    svg.selectAll("#actual")
        .attr("d", actualArea());
}

d3.select(window).on('resize', resize); 

d3.csv("areachart.csv", function(error, data) 
{
    data.forEach(function(d, i) 
    {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.actual = +d.actual;
    });

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.actual; })]);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "actual")
        .datum(data)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr("d", actualArea());

});

</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

While resizing, it seems to be set based on its original height vertically is because the svg area setting is not updated in `resize` function:

```
svg.selectAll("#actual")
   .attr("d", actual);
```

Here, the function used to draw `d` is still using the initial height:

```
var actual = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
.y0(height) // initial height
.y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.actual); });
```

Try to include height updating in resize function should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; any thoughts on how I might do this. All the things I have tried haven't worked. Thanks Andrew

Comment: Could you please post your code on plunker or jsfiddle? I am not sure where the second picture in your description came from.

Comment: I managed to get this working after carefully reading your answer. For anyone else reading this post, the second picture was the result of the chart when the window was expanded vertically. Andrew